# xs:choice - one and only one of the following nodes or one or more of the following nodes?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

few years ago I defined an XSD for my XML installer file. 
The goal was to define a requirements node with subnodes with different names like:

```
<requirements>
    <core version="1.0.0.1749" />
    <field version="1.2">chbxgroup</field>
    <php version="5.3"/>
</requirements>
```

The XSD for this part looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="requirements" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="core" type="requirement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="cms" type="requirement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="plugin" type="requirement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="application" type="requirement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="field" type="requirement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="php" type="requirement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And the requirement definition:

```
<xs:complexType name="requirement" mixed="true">
    <xs:attribute name="version" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\d+)?(\.)?(\d+)?" />
                <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="type" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="function|class" />
                <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
```

If you like, you can check the entire definition at: https://xml.sigsiu.net/SobiPro/application.xsd

Now the important information: **it works perfectly fine and exactly as we wanted it**

The issue is that we have a very curious and nice user who checked the definition and he is trying to learn about XML and XSD and he pointed me to the documentation at http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/el_choice.asp which clearly states that you that the "xs:choice" allows actually to use only one of the defined child nodes.

I was checking different docs on this and actually each of these is stating exact the same.
So for my understanding the way as we defined and as I learned it shouldn't really work. **But it does**

Some examples:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256109.aspx

> Allows **one and only one** of the elements contained in the selected
>   group to be present within the containing element.

http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp

> The  indicator specifies that either one child element or
>   another can occur:

So what is the real definition of "xs:choice"?

Does it allows really to use only one of the defined elements or it just limits the possible choice of the following child node to the defined elements?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Now, it is possible to connect the dots.

Your schema for `<requirements>` element is a **correct** schema for your XML.
According to it, indeed, all those children defined within the `xs:choice`
may repeat any number of times in any configuration.

That's because you have **unbounded** that `xs:choice`:

```
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

Here, the occurrence attributes `minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"` say
that this `xs:choice` may repeat itself any number of times (from 0 to infinite). 
Therefore, whatever specified in that `xs:choice` may repeat any number of times or mix with each other without limitations.

Concerning what **"xs:choice"** means... Yes, `xs:choice` (that is a single instance of it) allows using only one element among those defined within that choice. More precisely, the `xs:choice` allows you to use only one thing among those defined within it. Those 'things' (called 'particles') can be in fact not only elements, 
but also other choices, sequences, groups. So, you can construct quite complicated restriction with all that.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I pasted the same code twice - I just corrected it now.
Hope it better understandable :)